# Erro ao criar conexão com PHP

Tags: android, conexão, app

Ao criar a activity de conexão no campo connection.getRequestMethod("POST"); não aceita o método Post.

sou novato na área, poderiam me ajudar?

```
public static String postdados(String urlusuario, String parametrousuario) {

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try{

        url = new URL (urlusuario);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.getRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty( "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );

        connection.setRequestProperty( "content-lenght", "" + Integer.toString( parametrousuario.getBytes().length ) );

        connection.setRequestProperty( "content-language", "pt-BR");

        connection.setUseCaches( false );
        connection.setDoInput( true );
        connection.setDoOutput( true );

        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes(parametrousuario);
        dataOutputStream.flush();

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( inputStream, "UTF-8" ) );
        String linha;
        StringBuffer resposta = new StringBuffer();

        while ((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            resposta.append( linha );
            resposta.append( '\r' );
        }


            bufferedReader.close();
            return resposta.toString();


    } catch (Exception erro){

        return null;

    }finally {

        if (connection !=null){

            connection.disconnect();
        }


    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método para definir o tipo de envio é `setRequestMethod` e não `getRequestMethod` como foi utilizado, que deve ser trocado logo no topo da conexão para ficar da seguinte forma:

```
try{

    url = new URL (urlusuario);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); //agora com set
```

Atenção que o `content-length` também não está bem devido a uma erro de escrita:

```
connection.setRequestProperty( "content-lenght", ...
```

Deve então ficar:

```
connection.setRequestProperty( "content-length", "" + Integer.toString( parametrousuario.getBytes().length );
```

Comment: Muito obrigado isac. deu certinho.

Answer (score 0):

Você trocou o comando. No momento você está usando `getRequestMethod("POST")` quando deveria estar usando o `setRequestMethod("POST")`.
Tente trocar o `get` por `set` e veja se funciona.

Comment: Obrigado. Era isso mesmo.